# Chain rule and a square in the denominator

Tags: calculus

I have to find the derivative of $r/( \sqrt{r^2 +1})$ I know that i have to start with the quotient rule so I set it up like this $(\sqrt{r^2 +1})(1) - (r) (\text{the derivative of the denominator})$ I get $1/2(r^2 +1)^{-1/2}(2r)$ or $r^3+r$ so that gives me $(\sqrt{r^2 +1}) - (r^4 + r^2)$ which does not give me the right answer of $(\sqrt{r^2 +1})^{-3/2}$

Comment: Alternatively, any problem involving the quotient rule can be turned into a problem involving the product rule by using negative exponents. For this example, you could rewrite the rational function as
$$
r(r^2+1)^{-\frac{1}{2}}.
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct, you have to start with the quotient rule; and that the numerator of the expression you get will be $(r^2+1)(1) - r(\sqrt{r^2+1})'$; but I don't understand what you say later, and I don't see where you are dividing by the square of the numerator. So let me start from scratch.

We have:
$$\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dr}\frac{r}{\sqrt{r^2+1}} &= \frac{\left(\sqrt{r^2+1}\right)(r)' - r\left(\sqrt{r^2+1}\right)'}{\left(\sqrt{r^2+1}\right)^2}\\
&= \frac{\sqrt{r^2+1} - r\left(\sqrt{r^2+1}\right)'}{r^2+1}.
\end{align*}$$
(Since $(r)' = 1$, and $(\sqrt{r^2+1})^2 = r^2+1$). So we just need to figure out what the derivative of $\sqrt{r^2+1}$ is, substitute it in, and perhaps do some algebraic simplifications.

What is the derivative of $\sqrt{r^2+1}$? It's a Chain Rule, so:
$$\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dr}\sqrt{r^2+1} &= \frac{d}{dr}\left(r^2+1\right)^{1/2}\\
&= \frac{1}{2}\left(r^2+1\right)^{-1/2}(r^2+1)'\\
&= \frac{1}{2}\left(r^2+1\right)^{-1/2}\left( (r^2)' + (1)'\right)\\
&= \frac{1}{2}\left(r^2+1\right)^{-1/2}\left(2r + 0\right)\\
&= \frac{2r}{2}\left(r^2+1\right)^{-1/2}\\
&= \frac{r}{\sqrt{r^2+1}}.
\end{align*}$$

Now we plug that into the expression we had for the derivative of $\frac{r}{\sqrt{r^2+1}}$:
$$\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dr}\frac{r}{\sqrt{r^2+1}} &= \frac{\sqrt{r^2+1} - r\left(\sqrt{r^2+1}\right)'}{r^2+1}\\
&= \frac{\sqrt{r^2+1} - r\left(\frac{r}{\sqrt{r^2+1}}\right)}{r^2+1}\\
&= \frac{\sqrt{r^2+1} - \frac{r^2}{\sqrt{r^2+1}}}{r^2+1}.
\end{align*}$$
Now we do a bit of algebra. We can separate the fraction and do some simplification:
$$\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dr}\frac{r}{\sqrt{r^2+1}} &= \frac{\sqrt{r^2+1}-\frac{r^2}{\sqrt{r^2+1}}}{r^2+1}\\
&= \frac{\sqrt{r^2+1}}{r^2+1} - \frac{\quad\frac{r^2}{\sqrt{r^2+1}}}{r^2+1}\\
&= \frac{(r^2+1)^{1/2}}{r^2+1} - \frac{r^2}{(r^2+1)\sqrt{r^2+1}}\\
&=\frac{(r^2+1)^{1/2}}{r^2+1} - \frac{r^2}{(r^2+1)(r^2+1)^{1/2}}\\
&= \frac{(r^2+1)^{1/2}(r^2+1)^{1/2}}{(r^2+1)(r^2+1)^{1/2}} - \frac{r^2}{(r^2+1)(r^2+1)^{1/2}} &&\text{(common denominator)}\\
&= \frac{r^2+1}{(r^2+1)^{3/2}} - \frac{r^2}{(r^2+1)^{3/2}}\\
&= \frac{r^2+1-r^2}{(r^2+1)^{3/2}}\\
&= \frac{1}{(r^2+1)^{3/2}}\\
&= (r^2+1)^{-3/2},
\end{align*}$$
or else we can do the simplification directly on the fraction we had already:
$$\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dr}\frac{r}{\sqrt{r^2+1}} &= \frac{\sqrt{r^2+1}-\frac{r^2}{\sqrt{r^2+1}}}{r^2+1}\\
&= \frac{\quad\frac{r^2+1}{\sqrt{r^2+1}} - \frac{r^2}{\sqrt{r^2+1}}\quad}{r^2+1}\\
&= \frac{\quad\frac{r^2+1-r^2}{\sqrt{r^2+1}}\quad}{r^2+1}\\
&= \frac{\quad\frac{1}{\sqrt{r^2+1}}\quad}{r^2+1}\\
&= \frac{1}{(r^2+1)\sqrt{r^2+1}}\\
&= \frac{1}{(r^2+1)^{3/2}}\\
&= (r^2+1)^{-3/2}.
\end{align*}$$

Comment: I lost you at the part with $r^2 + 1^{1\2} on the top and then it dissapeared.

Comment: @Jordan: I don't know what you are refering to. I don't have any "$1^{1/2}$.  Can you tell me which display it is (first, second, third, fourth, or fifth), and which line in that display?

Comment: "Now we do a bit of algebra" between the third and fourth part I do not know what you did.

Comment: @Jordan: I divided: the numerator is $(r^2+1)^{1/2}$, The denominator is $r^2+1 = (r^2+1)^1 = (r^2+1)^{1/2}(r^2+1)^{1/2}$. One of the factors cancels, and you are left with just $\frac{1}{(r^2+1)^{1/2}}$.

Comment: Thanks I get it now, unfortunately I am to a point in the problems where I am no longer able to solve any of them on my own. Most likely I will just fail the test on monday.

Comment: @Jordan: I changed it a bit; is this clearer?

Comment: Yes, I just didn't quite understand before that a square root could be divided like that but now I understand.

Comment: @Jordan: Again, you are being hampered because you don't have strong enough algebra skills: if $a\geq 0$, then$$a^{1/2}a^{1/2} = a^{(1/2)+(1/2)} = a^1 = a.$$ Equality is not just "one-way": if $a\gt 0$, then you can go from $a^{1/2}a^{1/2}$ to $a$, and you can go from $a$ to $a^{1/2}a^{1/2}$.

Answer (score 3):

You could also write the quotient as a product:
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}r}r(r^2+1)^{-1/2}
&=(1)(r^2+1)^{-1/2}+r(-1/2)(r^2+1)^{-3/2}(2r)\\
&=(r^2+1)^{-1/2}-\frac{r^2}{r^2+1}(r^2+1)^{-1/2}\\
&=\frac{1}{r^2+1}(r^2+1)^{-1/2}\\
&=(r^2+1)^{-3/2}
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you've quite applied the chain rule properly. You're trying to differentiate $\sqrt{r^2 + 1}$, which is $(r^2 + 1)^{1/2}$. The derivative of this is $\frac{1}{2}(r^2 + 1)^{\underline{\underline{-1/2}}}\times 2r$ - the double underlined bit is the bit I think you forgot.

Comment: I had that but didn't post it I guess, I will fix it.

Comment: @Jordan: you definitely didn't have that. All of your later working followed as if it was just $(r^2+1)$. In other news, don't forget that you have to divide by the square of the denominator to apply the quotient rule, which (on second reading) it doesn't look like you've done.

Comment: That is what I forgot I think.